# How can I display a modal after a delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load a modal 2 seconds after the page has been loaded. I tried setting the state on `componentDidUpdate` but I keep on getting `active: undefined` The active props determines the visibility of the modal on the page. I tried toggling it to true on browser on the react tool and my modal shows up. I'm just not sure how to load to it 2 seconds after the page loads up.

```
  state = { show: true };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

render() {
const { showModal } = this.state;

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    ....
    <Modal.ModalAnimator active={showModal} onClose={this.closeModal}>
      <Modal.ModalWithCross
        onClose={this.closeModal}
      >
        <h3>Are you interested in any other Additions?</h3>
        <Section>
          <p>Hit “notify concierge” and we’ll be in touch shortly.</p>
        </Section>

      </Modal.ModalWithCross>
    </Modal.ModalAnimator>
  </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Comment: You want to use `componentDidMount` as your starting point. Where is the code your tried to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When destructuring the state, you write `showModal` instead of the actual state field name `show`. So your first lines in the `render` function should read:

```
render() {
  const { show } = this.state;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      ...
      <Modal.ModalAnimator active={show} onClose={this.closeModal}>
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
state = { show: true };

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ show: true });
        }, 2000);
    }

    render() {
        const { showModal } = this.state;
        return (

        let model = null;
        if (this.state.show) {
            let model = (
                <Modal.ModalAnimator active={showModal} onClose={this.closeModal}>
                    <Modal.ModalWithCross
                        onClose={this.closeModal}
                    >
                        <h3>Are you interested in any other Additions?</h3>
                        <Section>
                            <p>Hit “notify concierge” and we’ll be in touch shortly.</p>
                        </Section>
                    </Modal.ModalWithCross>
                </Modal.ModalAnimator>
            )
        }
        <React.Fragment>
            ....
        {model}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
    }
```